# How to create the boot device for ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64?

Tags: boot, 18.04

I have downloaded ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64 official website of Ubuntu and tried to create boot device many times with rufus, NNETBOOTIN, universal usb installer and they all failed to create the boot device for it.
Rufus says *fail to scan the image* then I downloaded Ubuntu again thinking that
it didn't download correctly but same error occured again and any of the tool not work for me. 
I am using Windows 10 professional edition.

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Comment: Possibly also useful : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  (ie. *how to verify the ISO download was perfect, then post-write to install-media, how to ensure the write was flawless*)

Comment: I agree with @guiverc: Start by verifying that the downloaded iso file is good. After that you can use a **cloning** method to create a USB boot drive, for example with **Rufus in dd-mode** or with [**Win32 Disk Imager**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb). If still problems, analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: Disk imager created the boot device but I cant boot from it when i try to boot from it from the boot manue by selecting usb widows automatically starts normally

Comment: I also make a try on installing it in virtual box but it says system halted no bootable media found even after I specified the path of the iso

Comment: after that i have selected boot medium manually by pressing F12 then it says cannont read from the medium